# MySQL query to display chat history between logged-in user and other users

Tags: mysql, chat

Developing user chat inside a web-app.

**Goal:** display list of users in desc order with whom logged in user has had a chat and near each such user - the last message (written by either that user or the logged in user).

**Current MySQL query:**

```
SELECT id,
       user_to,
       user_from,
       body, 
       msg_time
FROM chat
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM chat WHERE user_to=:id 
             OR user_from=:id
             GROUP BY user_to,user_from)
ORDER BY msg_time DESC
```

Works well. But! For a chat of any User A with any User B, current request displays 2 rows: one with most recent message sent by User A to User B, and one most recent message sent by User B to User A. While I need 1 row (under a "row" I mean a bootstrap row of data, where column 1 is icon of user with whom the chat takes place, column 2 is latest message between those 2 users and column 3 is time of that last messsage).

However, the request should display that User A and User B had a chat, and only display this once, with the most recent message made between User A and B.

Blown my brain over it. I want to keep the query short and feelin I am close, but cant finally solve this one. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: try adding something like `and user_to > user_from` in the inner query to break the symmetry

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and replace the `user_id` with the current logged in user id and then try

```
SELECT id,
   user_to,
   user_from,
   body, 
   msg_time
   FROM chat
 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) 
         FROM chat WHERE user_to=:id 
         OR user_from=:id
 GROUP BY IF (`user_from`=:user_id, `user_to`,`user_from`) )
 ORDER BY msg_time DESC
```